# Kafka Confluent Error while fetching metadata with correlation

Tags: apache-kafka

I have setup Kafka cluster with 3 nodes and everything was fine.

Three broker's with properties :

```
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
zookeeper.connect=109.169.xx.xx:2181,88.150.xxx.xxx:2181,5.152.xxx.xxx:2181
```

and `broker.id` is unique for each one .I stopped and started one of the brokers:

```
/opt/kafka/confluent-4.0.0/bin/kafka-server-stop
```

and

```
nohup /opt/kafka/confluent-4.0.0/bin/kafka-server-start /opt/kafka/confluent-4.0.0/etc/kafka/server.properties &
```

Now when I want to cunsome :

```
/opt/kafka/confluent-4.0.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server  109.169.xxx.xx:9092 --topic test_set_retention_nwq --from-beginning
```

This error message appears:

```
[2018-04-16 15:51:40,974] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-13964] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 14 : 
{test_set_retention_nwq=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-04-16 15:51:41,075] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-13964] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 15 : 
{test_set_retention_nwq=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-04-16 15:51:41,176] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-13964] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 16 : 
{test_set_retention_nwq=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-04-16 15:51:41,278] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-13964] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 17 : 
{test_set_retention_nwq=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Comment: Is your topic realy exist ? 

Do you find it when you run : `/opt/kafka/confluent-4.0.0/bin/kafka-topics --zookeeper 109.169.xx.xx:2181 --list` ?

Comment: yes. I run this command and  topic is there @QuentinGeff

Comment: ok can you check that your zookeeper instances run correctly ? ; 109.169.xx.xx:2181,88.150.xxx.xxx:2181,5.152.xxx.xxx:2181

Comment: How can I make sure that zookeeper works?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps.

1. Add the following lines in server.properties (for 3 brokers) file:

   ```
   listeners=PLAINTEXT://host.name:port
   advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://host.name:port
   ```

   where `host.name` is the IP address or host name of the Kafka broker.
2. Restart the Kafka brokers and test.